# How to check equilibrium solutions and stability of a non-linear problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I am having some difficulties in finding the stability of the following equilibrium solutions:

If:

$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-a(N-b)^{2}$

To find all equilibrium solutions I simply did:

$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-a(N-b)^{2}=0$

I found the following solutions: $0,\frac{-\sqrt(a)+ab}{a},\frac{\sqrt(a)+ab}{a}  $

And these are the equilibrium solutions.

Then to check stability, I simply calculated the derivative of $\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-a(N-b)^{2}$ and I obtained: $-r(-1+a(N-b)^{2})$.

To check stability I know that I can plug in my equilibrium solutions in here: $-r(-1+a(N-b)^{2})$

For Equilibrium solution $0$ it gives:  $-r(-1+a(0-b)^{2})=r-ab^{2}r$

For Equilibrium solution $\frac{-\sqrt(a)+ab}{a}$ it gives: $-r(-1+a((\frac{-\sqrt(a)+ab}{a})-b)^{2})=0$

For Equilibrium solution $\frac{\sqrt(a)+ab}{a}$ it gives: $-r(-1+a((\frac{\sqrt(a)+ab}{a})-b)^{2})=0$

I saw that because the last two give the value of $0$ I need to do further analysis by analyzing values at the right and left side. But as this is not a linear problem( with actual values) how can I check stability in this case?

Can anyone help me on this and let me know if what I did is correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but in this case I am trying to solve this analytically without the direction fiel plot. I believe that is $a>0$ as I need $\sqrt(a)>0$ and I cannot divide by zero. Is what you are asking?

Comment: Thank you. I will check the links.

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to solve this without giving values to a,b and r. Also the links you sent, use equilibrium solutions with values. In my case for two equilibrium solutions I have an expression and not a value. Do you know where I can find information about this? I am trying to find examples online but so far I didn't find anything which is similar to my problem. Thanks

Comment: Stability analysis via linearization is useful for **multi-dimensional** systems.  But in the case of one DE, with the RHS so regular as to guarantee uniqueness and, moreover, with isolated equilibria, it is just a nuisance.  For such $x' = f(x)$, if $x_1 < x_2$ are equiilbria and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$ in between then $x_1$ is unstable from the right and $x_2$ is asymptotically stable from the left, with its left attraction basin being just $(x_1, x_2)$, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the right-hand side function be $f(N) = rN\left(1 - a\left(N - b\right)^2\right)$. In what follows, suppose $r\neq 0$; otherwise $f(N) = 0$ for $r=0$. We first examine some simple cases.

> Suppose $a=0$, then $N=0$ is the only equilibrium solution and $f'(N) = r$ in this case. Consequently, $N = 0$ is unstable if $r>0$ and stable if $r<0$.
>
> Suppose $a<0$, then $N=0$ is the only equilibrium solution since $\left(1 - a\left(N - b\right)^2\right)> 0$ for any $N$ and $b$. As we shall see later, $f'(0) = r\underbrace{(1 - ab^2)}_{\ge 1}$ and so $N = 0$ is again unstable if $r>0$ and stable if $r<0$.

For the remaining of the analysis, we will suppose $a>0$ so that we have three equilibrium solutions. You are correct that you need to find $f'(N)$ to determine the stability of the equilibrium solutions, but you computed $f'(N)$ wrongly. Observe that $f(N)$ is the product of $rN$ and $\left(1 - a\left(N - b\right)^2\right)$ so we use Product Rule to find $f'(N)$:
\begin{align*}
f'(N) & = \underbrace{r\left(1 - a\left(N - b\right)^2\right)}_\textrm{This is what you had} + \underbrace{rN\left(-2a(N-b)\right)}_\textrm{This is what you were missing} \\
& = r\left(1 - a\left(N - b\right)^2\right) - 2raN(N-b).
\end{align*}
For $N_1 = 0$, we have 
$$ f'(0) = r\left(1 - ab^2\right). $$
For $N = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + b = N_2$, we have $N - b = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ and so 
\begin{align*}
f'\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + b\right) & = r\left(1 - a\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)\right) - 2ra\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + b\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \\
& = -2ra\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{a}b}{a}\right) \\
& = -2r\left(1 + \sqrt{a}b\right).
\end{align*}
For $N = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + b = N_3$, we have $N - b = -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ and so
\begin{align*}
f'\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + b\right) & = r\left(1 - a\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)\right) - 2ra\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} + b\right)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \\
& = 2ra\left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{a}b}{a}\right) \\
& = 2r\left(-1 + \sqrt{a}b\right) \\
& = -2r\left(1 - \sqrt{a}b\right). 
\end{align*}

**We now perform a case analysis.**
Observe that $f'(N) = 0$ for all three equilibrium solutions $N_1, N_2, N_3$ if $1-ab^2 = 0$, so suppose not. Also observe that $ab^2>0$ since we assume $a>0$ which means that $1-ab^2$ can either be negative or positive. For notational convenience, let $\lambda = \sqrt{a}b$. Then
\begin{align*}
f'\left(N_1\right) & = r\left(1 - \lambda^2\right) \\
f'\left(N_2\right) & = -2r\left(1 + \lambda\right) \\
f'\left(N_3\right) & = -2r\left(1 - \lambda\right) \\
\end{align*}

- Suppose $1 - \lambda^2 > 0$, then $\lambda^2 - 1 < 0 $ and this implies $-1 < \lambda < 1$, or 
  $$ 1 + \lambda > 0 \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ 1 - \lambda > 0. $$
- Suppose $1 - \lambda^2 < 0$, then $\lambda^2 - 1 > 0$ and this implies $\lambda < -1$ and $\lambda > 1$, or 
  $$ 1 + \lambda < 0 \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ 1 - \lambda < 0. $$

**We can finally determine the stability of each of the equilibrium solutions.**

1) For $1 - \lambda^2 > 0$,

- If $r > 0$, then $N_1$ is unstable and both $N_2, N_3$ are stable.
- If $r < 0$, then $N_1$ is stable and both $N_2, N_3$ are unstable.

2) For $1 - \lambda^2 < 0$,

- If $r > 0$, then $N_1$ is stable and both $N_2, N_3$ are unstable.
- If $r < 0$, then $N_1$ is unstable and both $N_2, N_3$ are stable.

Comment: I understood now. Thank you very much.